# How do I use two different protos in a an same process of gRPC Service

Tags: grpc-c#

I have two different client and uses the same gRPC Service. Each client runs independently and will request gRPC Service for different information. How do I manage in a same gRPC Process using two different Protos.

I am new to this, Looking for leads

Comment: Please post some information about what you are trying to do in your client/server, how you are defining your protos, how you are compiling them and what error you are actually seeing. Without all this information, it is very hard to help.

Comment: I resolved myself. by adding  endpoints.MapGrpcService<GreeterService1>();  endpoints.MapGrpcService<GreeterService2>();